# Xcode Storyboard Organization and Duplication of Effort

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboard

[image: A portion of my iPhone storyboard with spaghetti segues]
You can see that the segues are a mess of spaghetti.  To make sense of it, here are some possible paths that a user could take:

1. Tap a row in TopPlacesTVC --> Tap a row in PhotoSelectorTVC --> PhotoViewerVC
2. Tap a row in TopPlacesTVC --> Tap Map button in PhotoSelectorTVC --> Tap a pin in MapVC --> PhotoViewerVC
3. Tap Map button in TopPlacesTVC --> Tap a pin in MapVC --> Tap map button in PhotoSelectorTVC --> Tap a pin in MapVC --> Tap a row in PhotoSelectorTVC --> PhotoViewerVC

To make the segues cleaner, I could break it up into more view controllers so that each view controller has only 1 segue going into it.  However, this will introduce massive duplication of effort.  Currently, all of the above routes are achieved with 4 view controllers in the storyboard.  Breaking it up as proposed will require 5 new view controllers where each one is an exact duplicate of an existing VC.

Both options seem poor.  A spaghetti factory of segues defeats one of the main reasons for using a storyboard: The flow of the app is no longer clear.  On the other hand, introducing huge duplication of effort is not good, either.  Are there any ideas on keeping storyboards organized without duplicated view controllers?

Please no answers along the lines of "Don't use interface crappy builder."  If you don't like it, that's fine.  This question isn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may create one duplicate of MapVC for the third case and put it between the TopPlacesTVC and PhotoSelectorTVC.
[image]